# Error in passing argument to a controller function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, httpexception

I am trying to pass a variable $id to Controller function in routes file.

Following are the snippets from the respective files:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/news-post/{$id}', 'BlogController@getPost');
```

**BlogController.php**

```
public function getPost($id)
    {
            $post = \App\blog::find($id);
            if($post == NULL){
                App::abort(404);
            }
            return View('webpages.news-post',['title'=>$post['title'],'post'=>$post]);
    }
```

I am getting a  **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

I have tried searching for the reason but unable to find any.

Comment: Please check the answer below. Hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the route from

```
Route::get('/news-post/{$id}', 'BlogController@getPost');
```

to:

```
Route::get('/news-post/{id}', 'BlogController@getPost');
```

Remove the dollar sign before the id in the route. Check the example in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#required-parameters). Hope this helps.